# How to run code after hook_node_delete has completely run?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a node to which I have a number of images attached through the usual content type image field mechanism.  The attachment is done correctly, such that when I delete the node, the images are also deleted.

My problem is that these images are held in a subdirectory, which is not deleted by the file deletion process, and I end up with a bunch of empty and useless directories littering my file system.  I tried deleting the directory with `hook_node_delete()`, but this fails because Drupal hasn't yet gotten around to deleting the images when that hook gets called, and the `rmdir()` function I was using to delete the directory fails because the directory isn't empty.

So: Is there a hook I can call that will run after the files have been deleted?  I suppose I could write my own code in `hook_node_delete()` to delete the files and then the directory, but I'd rather not hack around the architecture like that, if possible.

Comment: According to the docs, `This hook is invoked from node_delete_multiple() after the type-specific hook_delete() has been invoked, but before hook_entity_delete and field_attach_delete() are called, and before the node is removed from the node table in the database.` so have you tried doing this in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_delete/7 ?

Comment: Aha -- mymodule_field_attach_delete works nicely -- thanks!  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into [hook_field_attach_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_delete/7).  This runs after all fields have been removed from a node/entity.  So, if all the file fields (and the actual files) have been removed, and all of them in such a node are all in one directory and they are the only files in that directory, removing that directory in this hook should succeed.

Comment: Works fine for me (although I see the value in the _file_delete() approach)

Answer (score 1):

You could try instead using

[`hook_file_delete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_delete/7)

> Respond to a file being deleted. - $file: The file that has just been deleted.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_delete
 */
function MYMODULE_file_delete($file) {
  // Attempt to delete empty file directory, on error resume next
  @drupal_rmdir(dirname(drupal_realpath($file->uri)));
}
```

Might not need drupal_realpath, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks / interesting, but I think the field_attach_delete is cleaner.

Comment: `hook_field_attach_delete` is for acting on all attached fields, `hook_file_delete` is specifically for acting on files only. That suggests the latter is simpler / cleaner IMO.

Comment: I think both work equally cleanly; but this one will make sure the directory is really removed regardless of what other logic is out there in the system, eg, no matter what, when you remove the last file in that directory, the directory will get removed as well.