# Which hook for code after a node has been deleted from the DB?

Tags: hooks

I'm running Drupal 7 and I want to re-save the user account of the node author after deleting a node of content type **picture**.  I want to do this because I have some code called in `hook_user_presave()` that counts the number of pictures a user has added and saves it in an integer field in the user.

I looked at `hook_node_delete()` and `hook_entity_delete()` as suggested in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101180/how-to-run-code-after-hook-node-delete-has-completely-run), but when then are invoked, the node is not yet deleted, so if I save the user at that point, the int value is one more than it should be (because the deleted file has not actually been deleted yet).

Is there a hook for responding to node deletion after it has taken place?

Related question: [Hook for reacting after adding node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178951/what-hook-for-triggering-an-action-after-saving-a-new-node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one. If you look at [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7), which `node_delete` is a wrapper function for, you can see that the only hook invocations (the above hooks) are triggered before the DB delete statements.

If your Drupal site only allows deleting through the **node/$nid/delete** form, one alternative to a post-delete hook is appending a submission handler to the node deletion confirmation form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_delete_confirm_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_delete_confirm_submit';
}

function MYMODULE_node_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //@TODO: Post-node-delete code here
}
```